# How can I prevent docker compile a library every time I deploy to bitbucket? Is there any bitbucket pipeline cache?

Tags: docker, opencv, cmake, docker-compose, dockerfile

We have our Flask API in a docker image, we push this docker to a bitbucket repository, then a bitbucket pipeline start deploying.

Everything works as expected, but the compilation of OpenCV is taking in average 15 min.

I would like to know if is there any way to avoid this compilation every time we push to bitbucket. Something like caching.

I have read about cache on bitbucket pipelines but it did not work as I expected.

This is part of my Dockerfile I would like to improve:

```
RUN mkdir /opt && cd /opt && \
  wget -q https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip && \
  unzip ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip && \
  rm -rf ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip && \
  mkdir -p /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build && \
  cd /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build && \
  CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ CC=/usr/bin/clang cmake \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D WITH_FFMPEG=NO \
  -D WITH_IPP=NO \
  -D WITH_OPENEXR=NO \
  -D WITH_TBB=YES \
  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=NO \
  -D BUILD_DOCS=NO \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python2=NO \
  -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
  -D ENABLE_PYTHON3=ON \
  -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \  
  .. && \
  make VERBOSE=1 -j8 && \
  make && \
  make install && \
  rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}
```

I expect some solution like just pointing a pre-compiled version of the OpenCV Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently faced this problem and agree that cache doesn't seem to work as expected. However without looking at your entire `Dockerfile`, it's hard to say. `ADD`'s and `COPY`'s will invalidate the cache so i'd suggest you move this section up to the top if you can before adding any files.

A better solution (if there is no pre-compiled version), is to use the concept of a base image which is what I have done to cut my build time down in half. Basically you build a base image `flask-api-base` which will install all your packages and compile OpenCV and then your actual final image will pull `FROM flask-api-base:latest` and build your application specific code. Just remember if the base image changes, you may need to wipe your Bitbucket cache.

Comment: I've decide to implement this solution since it looks the most simple one here.

The final image creation is already faster, now I am going to test the bitbucket deploy pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to create my own image, upload it to Docker hub, and create a new one based on that.

So the first docker image should contain all the basic libraries my system uses.
The second has the environmental variables and the api itself.